# Android: Getting rid of “Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns” Play Store warning

Tags: android, encryption, google-play

I have recently started to receive a Play Store warning like this: “Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns” and in order try to get rid of it (and having no idea what does exactly means) I created a "complex" structure regarding encription in my app as follows:

1) This next method (located in a class different than Cryptography one just in case) stores cipher preferences in two places, the "real" values in SharedPreferences, and the "default" values in application class setter called AppSettings ("default" means the default value that is required in order to get a SharedPreference if it fails to find one).

```
public static void setCryptPreferences()
{
  Context context = AppSettings.getContext();
  AppSettings appSettings = AppSettings.getInstance();

  String[] defCryptoValues = new String[]{ "AES", "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "UTF-8"};
  appSettings.setDefCryptValues(defCryptoValues);

  AWUtils.setSharedPreference(context, "CRYPT_ALGORITHM", "AES");
  AWUtils.setSharedPreference(context, "PADDING", "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  AWUtils.setSharedPreference(context, "CHAR_ENCODING", "UTF-8");
}
```

And I set them with this function on app startup.

2) Then, whenever I need to encrypt, I use them with this next method:

```
public static String cipherText(String plainText)
{
    AppSettings appSettings = AppSettings.getInstance();

    Cryptography crypto = new Cryptography();
    String[] defCryptoValues = appSettings.getDefCryptValues();
    String[] cryptoParams = Cryptography.getCryptoParams(defCryptoValues);

    return crypto.encrypt(plainText, cryptoParams);
}
```

And finally this is the real crypt method:

```
private String encrypt(String text, String[] cryptedParams)
{
    checkKeys();

    if (text == null) return null;
    String retVal = null;

    try {
        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(mCryptKey.getBytes(cryptedParams[2]), cryptedParams[0]);
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(mCryptIV.getBytes(cryptedParams[2]));

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cryptedParams[1]);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(cryptedParams[2]));
        retVal = new String(encodeHex(encrypted));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

I don't understand very clearly the warning, and I thought I is related of having the encrypt params

```
"CRYPT_ALGORITHM", "AES"
"PADDING", "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
"CHAR_ENCODING", "UTF-8"
```

as plain text in the Cryptography class and so I created all this thinking on "hiding" them and thinking it could help me to get rid of it, but it hasn't. I have recently uploaded a new version of my app and the warning still remains there and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Hello @Jinson Paul. Haven't yet, and I'd really like so, as I don't like seeing warnings in my play store console.

Comment: @JinsonPaul did you resolve the issue

Comment: @ManishNegi no the warning is still there,

Comment: See https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925?hl=en . It's likely that the problem is that your key and iv are statically computed (same for every execution of your app).